# How can you pull HATEOAS API with Python?

Tags: python, django, hateoas

I need to pull data from API with pagination. I have sent them a support email but no reply just yet.

Here is the answer from their first email to me.

> The API has “pagination” implemented where results are
> segmented into blocks of 20 per response. In order to navigate through
> the pages HATEOAS links are provided in the “Link” header. These
> headers display the full endpoints required to go to the pages you
> want. If there are more pages of the result, header will contain
> custom String field - Link, which will contain URLs where other pages
> of the results can be reached.
>
> If there are more pages of the result, header will contain custom
> String field - Link, which will contain URLs where other pages of the
> results can be reached. For example: Link:

```
<https://api.com:123/public/cook> ; rel="first", <
https://api.com:123/public/cook?page=10> rel="last", <
https://api.com:123/public/cook?page=3> rel="next", <
https://api.com:123/public/cook?page=1> rel="prev"
```

Searching through "hateoas python" with Google only comes with how to create it and not how to pull the data.

So, how can I get the link from the header from this HATEOAS API? I am using the Python 3 with latest stable Django.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all you want to do is parse the Link header, then... there are packages to do that

[LinkHeader](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/LinkHeader/)

Convert from HTTP Header to useful data:

> > > parse(headers['Link']).to_py()
> > >       [['http://example.com/foo', [['rel', 'self']]], ['http://example.com', [['rel', 'up']]]]

Create a link header yourself:

> > > str(LinkHeader([['http://example.com/foo', [['rel', 'self']]],
> > >       ...                 ['http://example.com', [['rel', 'up']]]]))
> > >       'http://example.com/foo; rel=self, http://example.com; rel=up'

HATEOAS is easy when you realize its just following links around :)

Comment: Got it solved by pinging and iterate through until the API page is unavailable. Your solution is definitely neater.